# How to get installed app's icons with same size?

Tags: android, icons

I need to get icons of all installed applications. For this I'm using this method `getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(appPackageName)` but I get the icons with different sizes. I looked through a lot of topics about this. there is an option to use this method `public Drawable getFullResIcon(Resources resources, int iconId)` but it is only good for android 3.0 and higher, but I need from 2.1 to 4.2. I also tried to get the icons using `Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.drawable.icon)` but I not found enough information about that. Also there are options to compress large icons to the desired size, but the image quality is lost. Now I want to ask you: who knows how to get the icons of installed applications of the same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PackageManager.getApplicationIcon` or `ApplicationInfo.loadIcon` return icons with the original size in their applications.

If some app has an icon of a wrong size (not equal to 48x48 dp), you can do nothing about it.

You can however define your `ImageView` to display such icons with the size you define. Just use `android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp"` inside your xml instead of the usual `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the api demos under views. Then go to grid; there are some examples there that might help you.